# no null in /dev error

Tags: shell, command-line

I executed the following line:

```
which lsb_release 2&>1 /dev/null
```

Output:

```
error: no null in /dev
```

When I verified the error using the `ls /dev/null` command, `null` was present in `/dev`. Why is this error occurring? I could not decipher the problem.

**UPDATE**

I just tried the above `which` command on someone else's system, it worked perfectly without generating the error that I got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, redirections can occur anywhere in the command line, not necessarily at the end or start.

For example:

```
echo foo >spamegg bar
```

will save `foo bar` in the file `spamegg`.

Also, there are two versions of `which`, one is shell builtin and the other is external executable (comes with `debianutils` in Debian).

In your command:

```
which lsb_release 2>&1 /dev/null
```

by `2&>1`, you are redirecting the STDERR (FD 2) to where STDOUT is (FD 1) pointed at, not to `/dev/null` and this is done first.

So the remaining command is:

```
which lsb_release /dev/null
```

As there is no command like `/dev/null`, hence the error.

Note that, this behavior depends on whether `which` is a shell builtin or external executable, `bash`, `ksh`, `dash` do not have a builtin and use external `which` and that simply ignores the error, does not show any error message.

On the other hand, `zsh` uses a builtin `which` and shows:

```
/dev/null not found
```

So presumably, that specific error is shown by the builtin `which` of the shell you are using.

---

Also, it seems you wanted to just redirect the STDERR to `/dev/null` if `lsb_release` does not exist in the `PATH` i.e. `which` shows an error. If so, just redirect the STDERR to `/dev/null`:

```
which lsb_release 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I'm using bash and the same command is executing on another system and not on mine. And, the error that you've mentioned is a little different than what I'm encountering although the meaning is same.

Comment: Note `2&>1` is not `2>&1`.  In this case this will add `2` as a parameter, backgroup the run and then run `>1 /dev/null`.

Comment: I tried using `2>`, I'm still getting the same error. That is why so confused why it is happening this way with me

Comment: So, then it must be a `which` issue. I'll figure out what my system is using and alter the code to match my system.

Comment: @StephenHarris Ooops..edited..

Comment: @AbhimanyuSaharan Its a `which` issue..

Comment: The questioner's `which` is [GNU `which`](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Which), which produces that error.  It's not from a built-in.

Comment: @JdeBP I don't see that being mentioned anywhere..check OP's other comments too..

Comment: It doesn't need to be _mentioned_.  That's what it is.  You're basing an answer on the behaviour of the wrong `which`, stating that external `which` does not produce this error.  GNU `which` produces this very error.  _Hence the existence_ of all of those comments.  You and the questioner are not running the same `which` program.

Comment: @JdeBP I'm using GNU which.. could you reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the command `which lsb_release 2&>1 /dev/null` is wrong.

You probably meant to run `which lsb_release 2> /dev/null` assuming you're running an "sh" type shell.

If you're running `csh` type shell then you have more problems with stderr redirection.

Comment: I'm using `sh` type shell. I tried your solution too, same issue on my system.